# Print a column with awk inside a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I want to `print $2` however inside a for loop. I tried with the following

```
for i in {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21}; do
awk '{ print $${i} }' COLVAR >tmp_${i}
done
```

It gives syntax error. I tried also with `${${i}}` but still the syntax error. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: This is really bad design to have a loop in the shell to print columns in `awk` when you can do with `awk` itself

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie and trying to learn. Please bear with me

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
a b c d e
```

To use shell variables in awk, use `-v`:

```
$ for i in 2 3 4; do awk -v i=$i '{ print $i }' file; done
b
c
d
```

Usually the best is to do something like this entirely in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { split("2 3 4", a) } { for (i in a) print $i }' file
a
b
c
```